# Give a complete list of all the subgroup relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

There are nine groups given below. Give a complete list of all the subgroup relations, written in the form $G_i ≤ G_j$, that exist between these given groups $G_1, G_2, ..., G_9$.

• $G_1 = \mathbb{Z}$ under addition.

• $G_2 = 12\mathbb{Z}$ under addition.

• $G_3 = \mathbb{Q}^+$ under multiplication.

• $G_4 = \mathbb{R}$ under addition.

• $G_5 = \mathbb{R}^+$ under multiplication.

• $G_6 = \lbrace (√3)^n| n ∈ \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ under multiplication.

• $G_7 = 3\mathbb{Z}$ under addition.

• $G_8 =$ the set of all integral multiples of
6 under addition.

• $G_9 = \lbrace 6^n| n ∈ \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ under multiplication.

I believe $G_2 ≤ G_8 ≤ G_7 ≤ G_1 ≤ G_4$ would be a list for the addition groups.

You would also have  $G_3 ≤ G_5$ and $G_6 ≤ G_5$ but what about $G_9$ is it just by itself? Is this all the subgroup relations?

Comment: You list $G_6$ as one of the addition groups. Is that meant to be $G_8$?

Comment: Yes, $G_6$ was suppose to be $G_8$ in the addition group

Comment: Also, note that all the elements of $G_9$ are positive rational numbers.